# Python: Efficient split column in pandas DF

Tags: python, performance, pandas, split

Suppose I have a DF that contains a column of a form

```
0     A.1
1     A.2
2     B.3
3     4.C
```

And suppose that I want to split this columns by '.' using only the element after '.'. A naive way to do that would be

```
for i in range(len(tbl)):
  tbl['column_name'].iloc[i] = tbl['column_name'].iloc[i].split('.',1)[1]
```

This works. And it's very slow for large tables. Does anyone have an idea about how to speed up the process? I can use new columns in the DF so I am not restricted to changing the source column (as i reuse it in the example).
Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

`pandas` has string methods that do such things efficiently without loops (which **kill** performance). In this case, you can use [`.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/text.html#splitting-and-replacing-strings):

```
>> import pandas as pd
>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['A.1', 'A.2', 'B.3', 'C.4']})
>> df
    a
0   A.1
1   A.2
2   B.3
3   C.4
>> df.a.str.split('.').apply(pd.Series)
    0   1
0   A   1
1   A   2
2   B   3
3   C   4
```

Comment: Ami - Tavory worked like a miracle (slow miracle but not a 2h miracle :-) )! @maxymoo - Thank you for your answer. It is somewhat slower than the native pandas but much faster than the regular "for" loop! possibly that for certain cases this scenario is even better than the pandas parsing. Thank you both so much.

Answer (score 1):

For a large dataframe, it's must faster to use `map` rather than a for loop:

```
%timeit df['newcol']  = df.column_name.map(lambda x: x.split('.')[1])
100 loops, best of 3: 10.7 ms per loop

%timeit for i in range(len(df)): df['newcol'].iloc[i] = df['column_name'].iloc[i].split('.',1)[1]
1 loops, best of 3: 7.63 s per loop
```